# Unity android plugin - ads won't go on the bottom of screen

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a plugin so I can use Amazon Mobile Ads in Unity, but for some reason I can not get it to stick to the bottom of the screen. It always goes to the top of the screen. The app is in Landscape mode.

Here is the plugin code.

```
public class AmazonAds {

    public AmazonAds(){
    }

    public static void displayAd(final boolean test){ 
        UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                AdRegistration.setAppKey("APPKEY");
                AdRegistration.enableTesting(test);
                AdLayout adView = new AdLayout(UnityPlayer.currentActivity);
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext());
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                UnityPlayer.currentActivity.addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                layout.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                adView.loadAd(new AdTargetingOptions());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

What should I try to see if it fixes it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweet I fixed it! In case you want to know the answer, this is how you fix it.

```
AdRegistration.setAppKey("APPKEY");
AdRegistration.enableTesting(test);
adView = new AdLayout(UnityPlayer.currentActivity);
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext());
layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
UnityPlayer.currentActivity.addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
layout.addView(adView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));
```